# return insert id on none laravel db set up

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, postgresql, api

I have a database that was not designed for Laravel. I am building a small api using Laravel. Thus I can not useLlaravel structured queries. The query is working but need to be able to retrieve the id number of an insert.

This is the insert I am using.

```
$results = DB::insert("
            SELECT * FROM insrdata.add_user(
                :assocID,
                :accountID,
                :firstName,
                :middleName,
                :lastName,
                :address1,
                :address2,
                :city,
                :state,
                :zipCode,
                :phone,
                :email,
                :birthDateMMDDYYYY,
                :gradeLevelID,
                :commentText
            )
        ",
        [
            'assocID' => $request->input('assocID'), 
            'accountID' => $request->input('accountID'),
            'firstName' => $request->input('firstName'),
            'middleName' => $request->input('middleName'), 
            'lastName' => $request->input('lastName'), 
            'address1' => $request->input('address1'),
            'address2' => $request->input('address2'), 
            'city' => $request->input('city'), 
            'state' => $request->input('state'),
            'zipCode' => $request->input(''), 
            'phone' => $request->input(''),
            'email' => $request->input('email'), 
            'birthDateMMDDYYYY' => $request->input('birthDateMMDDYYYY'), 
            'gradeLevelID' => $request->input('gradeLevelID'),
            'commentText' => $request->input('commentText')
        ]
    );

if($results) {
    $return_array = array(
        'p_contact_id' => "",
        'p_result' => "O.K."
    );
}
```

I need to get the id of the insert.

Answer (score 0):

I think if the insert is successful, you can query for it by *accountID* (which i suppose unique for each inssured person) and get its id.

Answer (score 0):

This is a little complex without using the Laravel structured queries, as you said.  If you can tweak your query a little, and make sure you validate the input data ahead of your insert to prevent SQL injection, you should be able to use `insertGetId`.  You'll have to do some work, but something along the lines of:

```
$id = DB::table('whateverYourTableNameIs')->insertGetId([
    'assocID' => $request->input('assocID'),
    'yourSelectField' => DB::raw("yourRawSelect"),
    // etc.
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is called "getting last inserted id". Here documentation in Laravel about it.

https://laravelcode.com/post/laravel-55-get-last-inserted-id-with-example